# Moving textbox output into a different textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to output text into another text box once the first has 5 entries in it. Example; i give the scores 100,200,300,200,200. Now when I try to enter a new score it should place it in the next textbox, but doesent.

```
Dim Testint As Integer ' define an Integer for testing
    Dim sampleTextBox(3) As TextBox
    sampleTextBox(0) = txtPlayer1Scores
    sampleTextBox(1) = txtPlayer2Scores
    sampleTextBox(2) = txtPlayer3Scores
    sampleTextBox(3) = txtPlayer4Scores
    Dim sampleLabel(3) As Label
    sampleLabel(0) = lblPlayer1Average
    sampleLabel(1) = lblPlayer2Average
    sampleLabel(2) = lblPlayer3Average
    sampleLabel(3) = lblPlayer4Average

    scoreArray(textCount, gameNumber - 1) = CInt(txtScoreInput.Text) ' subtracting 1 from the score array
    sampleTextBox(textCount).Text &= " Score:" & scoreArray(textCount, gameNumber - 1) & vbCrLf
    'output statement
    gameNumber = gameNumber + 1 'increment the counter

    If gameNumber > MAX_SCORE_LENGTH Then

        sampleTextBox(textCount).Focus()
        sampleTextBox(textCount).Enabled = False
        For i As Integer = 0 To 4 'Add the array values up
            scoreTotal += scoreArray(textCount, i)
        Next
        playerAverage = scoreTotal / MAX_SCORE_LENGTH
        sampleLabel(labelCount).Text = playerAverage
        ' I need the textbox switch here
        textCount = textCount + 1 
        labelCount = labelCount + 1 ' and labels

ElseIf textCount > MAX_PLAYERS Then
        'calculate team average
        btnEnterScore.Enabled = False
    Else
        lblEnterScore.Text = "Enter Score for game #" & gameNumber ' 5 scores have not be inputted, 
        txtScoreInput.Text = "" 'ask for more
        txtScoreInput.Focus() 'refocus the input textbox
    End If
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you edit your question to make it clearer what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry, ill do that now

Comment: So, are you saying that, when the user tries to type the fifth comma into the `TextBox`, focus will automatically shift to a different `TextBox`?

Comment: fifth score into the first textbox, then the next score they input goes into the second text box, and will continue until all 4 multiline boxes have 5 scores each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it...setting the max length to 15 forces it to move on after 15 digits, it also works when there are less than 15 digits

```
txtscore1.MaxLength = 15
```